# rewrite ajax jquery call to coffeescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, coffeescript

How can I rewrite this code to coffeescript:

```
  $('.delete_action').click(function(event) {
    $.get('/delete_action?name=' + event.target.name + '&date=' + $(this).attr('date'), function(data) {
    });

    $(this).parent().remove();

    return false;
  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Humm, that's an easy task if you know coffeescript. So, learn it: http://arcturo.github.com/library/coffeescript/

And a js to coffee conversor:

http://js2coffee.org/

Which gives us:

```
$(".delete_action").click (event) ->
  $.get "/delete_action?name=" + event.target.name + "&date=" + $(this).attr("date"), (data) ->

  $(this).parent().remove()
  false
```

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
$('.delete_action').click (event) -> 
    $.get '/delete_action?name=' + event.target.name + '&date=' + $(this).attr('date'), (data) -> 

    $(this).parent().remove();

    false;
```

check here [1] and hit "try coffeescript" if you ever come across something this again

[1] http://coffeescript.org/